# Excel VBA - Ambiguous Name Prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I get the ambiguous name prompt with this excel vba:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUi As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(“DepartmentCode”).value = Range(“DepartmentCode”)
    ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(“DepartmentCode”).value = Range(“DepartmentCode”)
End Sub
```

There is another Public Sub Workbook_BeforeSave event in the same workbook which is also required. How do I work around this.

I have no knowledge of VBA. I found the string above on google. I am basically trying to synchronize data in excel with columns in SharePoint.

Would appreciate help on this.

How can I work around it? Sorry, I have no knowledge of vba. Just copied from google

Comment: You cant have two BeforeSave Events. Combine them.

Comment: If I may ask, why is this being downvoted? The OP includes the code, describes the problem, includes the actual error message -- what makes this not an ideal question? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the code in one event (that is, everything after the `Private Sub` line and before the `End Sub` line) and paste it into the other event, either right after the `Private Sub` or right before the `End Sub`. Then remove the whole event you copied from.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get a different error, variable not defined.

Comment: Hi, now I get a compile error: variable not defined. I followed instructions per http://123sharepoint.ch/archives/176

Comment: Would really appreciate a fix. Have been struggling with this for weeks! Thanks a lot.